# Cat urinates on his back paws; what should I do?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, urination, hygiene

I have two cats, the bigger-sized of whom often (once every two days) pees on his back paws.

Upon inspection, this doesn't seem to be his fault -- he's using the litter and litter box properly, but because he pees so much every time, the urine tends to "stream down" into where his back paw stands.

At first, I thought it was because the litter box is too small since he's the bigger one, so I upsized it to the biggest one I can get from Amazon, but this still happens.

Is there anything that I can do about this? Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Welcome to Pets! What type of litter do you use and have you tried different brands? Different litter absorbs moisture at different rates and coarser litter lets the liquid sink in faster, but some cats dislike how coarse litter feels.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks! I'm using this: https://www.petsmart.com/cat/litter-and-waste-disposal/litter/fresh-step-simply-unscented-cat-litter---clumping-multi-cat-5288003.html I think this is indeed quite fine-grained? Maybe I should try some coarser ones?

Comment: The disadvantage of coarser litter is that some cats refuse to use it (you should gradually mix more of the new litter into the old one over several days) and in my experience it doesn't clump together well. You'll either have to have a good scoop or waste some more of the litter when cleaning. If you find that coarser litter works, please don't hesitate to answer your own question.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks! Just ordered some coarse ones. Will definitely report back, possibly with an answer if that works!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to try much bigger boxes, we are not using commercially available litterboxes as even the large ones tend to be somewhat small, but instead use those plastic under-the-bed containers you can put your blankets in.

Those are about 50x90 centimeters (20x35 inches), and even the largest cats can use them comfortably with a lot of room to spare.

You'll need a lot of litter to initially fill them, think at least a full large bag, but the cats absolutely love them.

The more space they have to dig their little hole, the less likely any accidents are.